# Delay lighting switch

Tags: capacitor, delay

I want some 100 w bulbs in series to lit one after another on the same switch. How it can be done? Please suggest some methods

Comment: Without the addition of some control electronics and individual wires to each bulb there is no easy way.

Comment: Do you want the lamps to light up so that there's only one lit  at a time, or do you want them to light up, one after another, without the one previously lit one being turned off, so that at the end of the cycle they'll all be lit?

Comment: search " light chaser" triac

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean that all the lamps are wired in series, then what you ask is not possible.  One way or another you need individual control over the lamps, since you want them each to do something different.

If you just mean you want the bulbs to come on in a seires, then have the switch turn on a microcontroller.  This waits a little while to make sure the switch is really on (debouncing).  It then turns on a sequence of relays.  Each relay switches the power to one bulb.  The timing between enabling the relays is done in the firmware, so can be as flexible as you want.

Comment: He asked how to do it with the lamps in series.

Comment: @EMFi: I think he means he wants the bulbs to light in series.  I have added clarification to the answer.

Comment: If the lamp are wired in series one can come up with fancy solutions, but they all involve adding wires. Without additional info I would say that this idea is the best you can get.

Comment: @VladimirCravero:  I won't argue your point since it's still early-on in the discussion and one can't, from the OP's  question,  determine whether what's being asked for is a  one-hot or a thermometer display. I've asked the OP for clarification, so maybe we'll have - soon, hopefully - something to work with.

Comment: @EMFi: Whether the lamps should blink in sequence, or light up and stay lit in sequence, a micro driving relays is still a good answer.  The difference is just the firmware in the micro.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, you can keep the lamps wired in series if you can tap the connections between the lamps.  This then requires a current source or voltage-controllable power.  That's pretty complicated for the end result, though.

Comment: Maybe some sort of charlieplexing is possible, if taps are available

Comment: @OlinLathrop:  So, if the lamps needed to stay in series, as the OP  requested, what would be your solution?

Comment: @EMFI: As I said two comments above yours, it would get complicated.  This is very unlikely what the OP really wants, so I'm not going to get into it more than I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You could simple wire a time delay relay to each lamp, then power the lamp through the relay and set each relay for a slightly different time. Expensive, and likely more expensive than just adding something line a Programmable Logic Controller, but possible nonetheless.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUNNa4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>